# Can you explain to me how this code operates under the hood

Tags: recursion

```
def aa(a):
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return aa(a-1) + 1
```

I am able to understand the above recursion and how it is working.

However I cannot understand how this recursion is working. Can you help me?

```
def aa(a):
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return aa(a-1) + aa(a-1)
```

I tried debugging as well. The cursor was jumping places. Didnt help me figure it out .

Comment: What are you having trouble understanding? Would `return 2 * aa(a-1)` be clearer?

Comment: Try using [this](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) site. If you paste you python code into the box it should run fine.

Comment: I don't understand how it propagates. the flow of the code

Comment: When `aa` gets called, either it returns 1 (if `a` is 1), or it calls `aa` again twice, each time with `a-1` as a parameter. (Each of those calls follows the same process.)

Comment: the flow of the call is different from return 2 * aa(a-1)

Comment: Yes, in the latter case, `aa(a-1)` is only executed once.

Comment: And in the first case?

Comment: It's executed twice.

Comment: Then why do I have over 999 runs

Comment: Twice per invocation of `aa`. To be more explicit: if you call `aa(5)`, you'll see 2 invocations of `aa(4)` and 4 invocations of `aa(3)` and 8 invocations of `aa(2)` and 16 invocations of `aa(1)`. Each invocation of `aa(x)` results in two invocations of `aa(x-1)` except `aa(1)` which terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this on a simple level, say with a number like 2:

```
def aa(a):
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return aa(a-1) + aa(a-1)
```

Since 2 is greater than 1, we go straight to the else.

The else asks for us to evaluate `aa(a-1)` and then add `aa(a-1)` to it. To do this, we must first evaluate the leftmost value of this expression;

With a starting value of 2 it's easy to see that `aa(a-1)` is `aa(2-1)` or just `aa(1)` which will always return a value of 1 due to the first if statement. So the else will evaluate to `aa(1) + aa(1)` or simply `1 + 1`

So what happens when we pass an initial value of 3? The logic follows like this (bold are the functions that will be evaluated on the next line):

- 3 == 1 ? no
- **aa(3-1)** + aa(3-1)      `// aa(2) + aa(2)`

  - 2 == 1 ? no
  - **aa(2-1)** + aa(2-1)

    - 1 == 1 ? YEP, return 1
  - 1 + **aa(2-1)**

    - 1 == 1 ? YEP, return 1
  - 1 + 1
- 2 + **aa(3-1)**

  - 2 == 1 ? no
  - **aa(2-1)** + aa(2-1)

    - 1 == 1 ? YEP, return 1
  - 1 + **aa(2-1)**

    - 1 == 1 ? YEP, return 1
  - 1 + 1
- 2 + 2

Essentially you're evaluating the left side of the equation, and within that left side, you're evaluating a left and a right. But you evaluate the left first, then the left first etc. etc. until you finally get a result and then evaluate the right, continuing until you have an answer:

- **left** right

  - **left** right

    - value
  - value **right**

    - value
- value **right**

  - **left** right

    - value
  - left **right**

    - value
- value value